# Why data related to a URL is created before writing something?

Tags: swift4, xcode9.1

Xcode 9.1
Swift 4

I'm trying to do some things if a property list still doesn't exist at a certain URL. The code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let urlPers = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("punterosborrable.plist")
    lazy var infoPunt = try? Data(contentsOf: urlPers)



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        switch infoPunt {
        case nil:
            puntNUM = 1
            puntALG = 1
            puntGEO = 1
            puntDYA = 1
        default:
            puntNUM = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: infoPunt!)[0]
            puntALG = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: infoPunt!)[1]
            puntGEO = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: infoPunt!)[2]
            puntDYA = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: infoPunt!)[3]
        }
```

Supposedly, if I don´t write anything to the Url, infoPunt should have the value nil. However, just after running the line

```
 switch infoPunt {
```

the debugger shows that `infoPunt.storage = (Data?) some`

What does this mean? What value (or data) is infoPunt holding at this point? I thought it should be nil.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to be a memory-related error; when I try this, I get a crash on the `switch infoPunt` line, so possibly the variable is ending up pointing to invalid memory. If I declare the lazy variable as the result of a closure—i.e. `lazy var infoPunt = { return try? Data(contentsOf: urlPers) }()`, then it works. I'm not quite sure why this is, but there may be an issue involving the combination of `lazy` and `try?`—possibly a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka It worked like a charm. Thank you very much!!!